# What is the most intuitive proof that Gaussian kernel is positive definite?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I have general form of Gaussian kernel $K(x,x')=\exp(-\|x-x'\|^{2})$ (just not considering $\sigma$). I tried to prove its positive definiteness via Gram matrix properties, but couldn't. Is there any intuitive solution?

Comment: This needs more detail to be possible to answer.

Comment: explanation added

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix + https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130554/gaussian-kernels-why-are-they-full-rank